# how to see original error thrown in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, error-handling, webserver

I have a asp.net 2.0 web application in webserver deployed. One of the function have code like below:-

...

```
try
{
//Some System/.net Exception occurred
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
//Show custom message
}
```

...

As you can see the system/.net exception is caught in Catch block but the actual exception is not displayed or logged anywhere. How I can see the actual error which occurred in webserver without modifying the code?

The problem is I don't have the source code and I don't want to decompile the dlls and re-deploy the dlls after recreating the code.

Also, nothing is getting logged in the event log.

Is there a way or tool to find out which error has occurred in try...catch block to see the actual error message?

Comment: if it isn't logged, nor propagating up the call stack (application aborted), you just cannot.

Answer (score 0):

The commenter is correct.  You cannot intercept the exception if it's being suppressed.

However, if it's propagating up the call stack, then you can add a new IHttpModule and log the exception like so:

```
public class TheLogger : IHttpModule
{
    HttpApplication _ctx;

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        _ctx = context;
        _ctx.Error += _ctx_Error;
    }

    void _ctx_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ex = _ctx.Server.GetLastError();
        File.AppendAllText("c:\\log.txt", ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Adding a reference to the logged to the web.config:-

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="ExceptionLogger" type="ExceptionLogger.TheLogger, ExceptionLogger"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```